# How to filter strings from HTML tags in javascript with regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a solution that I could get string from HTML tags with regex as follow:

```
params.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
```

Above code is when html tag found, it replace with ''. But what I want to get like array list `['ppshein', 'male', 'javascript']` if my original string is `<b>ppshein</b><span>male</span><u>javascript</u>`

Please let me know how to do it, thanks.

Comment: you can use `match(/(?<=>)[^<]+(?=<)/g)` for the given sample, but parsing html with regex is full of issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used regex to remove tags and then split it then clear empty ones

```js
var string="<b>ppshein</b><span>male</span><u>javascript</u>";
var x=string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '[caps]').split("[caps]").filter(x=>x!="");
console.log(x);
```

Comment: That's kinda sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just split and remove the empty ones.

```
var string="<b>ppshein</b><span>male</span><u>javascript</u>";
var x=string.split(/<[^/].*?>(.*?)<\/.*?>/g).filter(x => (x != "")));
console.log(x);
```